# Find the intersection point and verifying its direction

Tags: calculus, geometry

The tangent to the curve $y = e^x$  drawn at the point $(c,e^c)$ intersects the line joining the points $(c – 1, e^{c-1})$ and $(c+1, e^{c+1})$

(A) on the left of x = c

(B) on the right of x = c

(C) at no point

(D) at all point

My approach is as follow

$y = {e^x},y' = {e^x} \Rightarrow y' = {e^c}$

$y = {e^c}x + {c_{in}}$

Where $c_{in}$ represent the y intercept

${c_{in}} = {e^c}\left( {1 - c} \right)y = {e^c}x + {e^c}\left( {1 - c} \right)$

The points are $\left( {c - 1,{e^{c - 1}}} \right)\& \left( {c + 1,{e^{c + 1}}} \right) \Rightarrow m = \frac{{{e^c}\left( {e - {e^{ - 1}}} \right)}}{2}$

$y = \frac{{{e^c}\left( {e - {e^{ - 1}}} \right)}}{2}x + c{'_{in}}$...eq(i)

${e^{c + 1}} = \frac{{{e^c}\left( {e - {e^{ - 1}}} \right)\left( {c + 1} \right)}}{2} + c{'_{in}} \Rightarrow {e^c}\left( {e - \frac{{\left( {e - {e^{ - 1}}} \right)\left( {c + 1} \right)}}{2}} \right) = c{'_{in}} \Rightarrow c{'_{in}} = {e^c}\left( {\frac{{ - e\left( {c - 1} \right) + {e^{ - 1}}\left( {c + 1} \right)}}{2}} \right)$

$y = \frac{{{e^c}\left( {e - {e^{ - 1}}} \right)}}{2}x + {e^c}\left( {\frac{{ - e\left( {c - 1} \right) + {e^{ - 1}}\left( {c + 1} \right)}}{2}} \right)$...eq(ii)

How we will proceed

Definitely we need to find the value of intersection **x** and see whether it is left or right of **c**

Answer (score 2):

There is more conceptual approach. Since the function $y=e^x$ is convex (concave upwards), tangent at a given point lies below the segment joining two points on either side of given point.

One can see geometrically, if upper line has more (positive) slope, the two lines intersect on the left and if the lower line has more (positive) slope, the two lines intersect on the right.

Slope of tangent is $m_T=e^c$

Slope of line is $$m_L=\dfrac{e^{c+1}-e^{c-1}}{2}$$

All one has to do is compare $m_T$ and $m_L$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Detailed solution can be found on Page 6

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwEaIp7y7BJTMU5jd3JvQl9rTEE/view